# SqlDataAdapter missing DeleteCommand

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am loading a VB.NET `DataGridView` using an `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet` and then setting the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` to the `DataSet`.

For some reason, the only command that is populated with the `SqlCommandBuilder` is the `SelectCommand`.  I realize I am only specifying a SELECT query, but I thought the purpose of the `SqlCommandBuilder` is to generate the Update/Delete/Insert command for me.

The following is the applicable code:

```
Dim _dstErrorLog As New DataSet
Dim _adapter As SqlDataAdapter
Dim _builder As SqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub ErrorLog_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call LoadErrorLog()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadErrorLog()
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "SELECT Ident, LogDate, LogDesc FROM dbo.ErrorLog ORDER BY DescDateTime DESC"
    _adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, dataLayer.Connection)
    _builder = New SqlCommandBuilder(_adapter)
    _adapter.Fill(_dstErrorLog)

    grdErrorLog.DataSource = _dstErrorLog.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub grdErrorLog_UserDeletingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles grdErrorLog.UserDeletingRow
    _adapter.Update(_dstErrorLog.Tables(0))
End Sub
```

When I delete a row, it disappears from the `DataGridView` but when I re-open the form, the data is all still there.  Do I need to specify the `DeleteCommand` myself?  And if so, then what is the purpose of the `SqlCommandBuilder`??

Answer (score 1):

Use the **UserDeletedRow** event, not the **UserDeletingRow**.
In the UserDeletingRow event the changes made to your DataGridView are still not committed to the DataSource binded, so calling the **SqlDataAdapter.Update** in that event doesn't result in any changes to the database because the table is still unchanged.

```
Private Sub grdErrorLog_UserDeletedRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdErrorLog.UserDeletingRow
    Dim count = _adapter.Update(_dstErrorLog.Tables(0))
    Console.WriteLine("Rows deleted:" & Count)
End Sub
```

Infact in the **UserDeletingRow** the argument `e` is a `DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs` meaning that you could still cancel the deletion setting `e.Cancel = True`

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick!  For some reason, the `DeleteCommand` still said "Nothing" when I set a breakpoint.  However, the data was successfully deleted from the data source, so it appears to work correctly.